# Generic radix sort

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, generics, floating-point

This started out with my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23040622/2644390) to [Radix Sort on an Array of Strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23038622/2644390). Since I intend to write a generic radix sort for my own purposes anyway, I continued a little bit, and here is a version tested on:

1. a fixed `std::array` of `unsigned` numbers, each treated as a fixed sequence of bytes from least-significant (right) to most-significant (left), to be sorted by natural order; and
2. an `std::vector` of `std::string`s, each treated as a variable-length sequence of characters from left to right, to be sorted by lexicographical order.

I will eventually make this more and more generic, but I am posting it here before it becomes extremely abstract. For now, it is not even parametrized with respect to ascending/descending order, but most interesting generalizations will be towards

- all scalar types: signed integers, floating-point, `enum`s, pointers, etc.;
- sequences (built-in arrays or standard containers) of previous types to be sorted lexicographically;
- tuples or structures of previous types to be sorted lexicographically;
- recursive application of the above.

Here it is ([live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/92d8bb688948b02d)):

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <iostream>

template<bool B>
using expr = std::integral_constant<bool, B>;

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

template <typename View, bool Var, bool Flip, size_t Radix>
class radix_sort
{
    template <typename I, typename S>
    void sort(I& idx, const S& slice) const
    {
        using A = std::array<size_t, (Var ? Radix + 1 : Radix)>;

        A count = {};
        I prev = idx;

        for (auto i : prev)
            ++count[slice(i)];

        A offset = {{0}};
        std::partial_sum(count.begin(), count.end() - 1, offset.begin() + 1);

        for (auto i : prev)
            idx[offset[slice(i)]++] = i;
    }

public:
    template <typename D>
    std::vector<size_t> operator()(const D& data) const
    {
        std::vector<size_t> idx(data.size());
        std::iota(idx.begin(), idx.end(), 0);

        if (data.size() < 2)
            return idx;

        View view;
        using R = decltype(data[0]);

        size_t width = Var ?
            view.size(*std::max_element(data.begin(), data.end(),
                [view](R a, R b) { return view.size(a) < view.size(b); }
            )) :
            view.size(data[0]);

        for (size_t d = 0; d < width; ++d)
        {
            size_t digit = Flip ? width - d - 1 : d;
            sort(idx, [&view, &data, digit] (size_t i) {
                return size_t(view.at(expr<Var>(), data[i], digit));
            });
        }

        return idx;
    }
};

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

struct int_view
{
    template<typename A>
    size_t size(const A& a) const { return sizeof(a); }

    template <bool B, typename E>
    unsigned char at(expr<B>, const E& elem, size_t pos) const
    {
        return (elem >> pos) & 0xFF;
    }
};

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

struct array_view
{
    template<typename A>
    size_t size(const A& a) const { return a.size(); }

    template <typename E>
    typename E::value_type
    at(std::false_type, const E& elem, size_t pos) const
    {
        return elem[pos];
    }

    template <typename E>
    typename E::value_type
    at(std::true_type, const E& elem, size_t pos) const
    {
        using T = typename E::value_type;
        return pos < elem.size() ? elem[pos] + T(1) : T(0);
    }
};

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

std::array<unsigned, 100>
numbers()
{
    return {{
        162, 794, 311, 528, 165, 601, 262, 654, 689, 748,
        450,  83, 228, 913, 152, 825, 538, 996,  78, 442,
        106, 961,   4, 774, 817, 868,  84, 399, 259, 800,
        431, 910, 181, 263, 145, 136, 869, 579, 549, 144,
        853, 622, 350, 513, 401,  75, 239, 123, 183, 239,
        417,  49, 902, 944, 490, 489, 337, 900, 369, 111,
        780, 389, 241, 403,  96, 131, 942, 956, 575,  59,
        234, 353, 821,  15,  43, 168, 649, 731, 647, 450,
        547, 296, 744, 188, 686, 183, 368, 625, 780,  81,
        929, 775, 486, 435, 446, 306, 508, 510, 817, 794
    }};
}

std::vector<std::string>
strings()
{
    return {
        "subdivides",
        "main street",
        "pants",
        "impaled decolonizing",
        "argillaceous",
        "axial satisfactoriness",
        "temperamental",
        "hypersensitiveness",
        "bears",
        "hairbreadths",
        "creams surges",
        "unlaboured",
        "hoosier",
        "buggiest",
        "mauritanians",
        "emanators",
        "acclaiming",
        "zouaves dishpan",
        "traipse",
        "solarisms",
        "remunerativeness",
        "solubilizing",
        "chiseled",
        "jugular",
        "ooziness",
        "toastier",
        "baud",
        "suffixed",
        "powerless tiding",
        "disassimilated",
        "gasps",
        "flirtier",
        "uh"
    };
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

template<typename G, typename S>
void test(G generate, S sort)
{
    auto data = generate();
    auto idx = sort(data);

    std::cout << "sorted data:" << std::endl;
    for (auto i : idx)
        std::cout << data[i] << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    test(numbers, radix_sort<int_view,   false, false, 256>());
    test(strings, radix_sort<array_view, true,  true,  128>());
}
```

I would appreciate the following:

1. General comments on both algorithm and style.
2. Any more specific comments on correctness and efficiency.
3. Is the code self-evident, so that no comments are practically needed? For instance, is it evident what "views" and "slices" are?
4. I think I'll find my way with signed integral and remaining types, but is there a clean, standard, portable way of obtaining integral representations of mantissa + exponent of floating-point numbers, or should one resort to type casts and bitwise operations according to IEEE standard representations?

---

**EDIT** Please note I made a slight simplification in `radix_sort::sort()` compared to my original post.

Answer (score 5):

## Style

You should reorder your headers in alphabetic order. It will help when you will have to check whether a header is already included or not:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>
```

You have many type names that are a single capital letter, which quite hinder readability. For example, you could change `A` into `Arr`. For many of them, I can't guess which "concept" should satisfy template parameter types. Apart from `T` and `U` for any type or `N` for any integral value, it is pretty uncommon to use a single capital letter.

You should also be consistent when naming your types: do you want them to be capitalized or not? If you want to be consistent, you could for example rename `expr` into `Expr`.

Generally speaking, the style is quite good: the indentation is clear, the lines are not too long and you don't seem to have any magic number besides `0xFF`. I wish I could always read code that clean.

## Idiomacity

In `radix_sort::sort`, you use member functions `begin` and `end`. It is now considered good style to write `std::begin` and `std::end` wherever possible so that you won't get into trouble if the code is changed. Moreover, in C++14, you will have `std::cbegin` and `std::cend` that rely on member `begin` and `end`. That means that pre-C++11 containers that do not provide member `cbegin` and `cend` can also be used.

Comment: Thanks! About capital letters: in general I use lowercase for both types and objects; and uppercase only for template parameters and single-letter private type aliases. Some template parameters are small words (like `View`, Radix`) but others are single-letter when context helps (e.g. `A = std::array`, `S& slice`, or `G generate`). I guess single-letter is what I should be more careful about. For instance, `R = decltype(data[0])` is apparently a (`const`) reference to some type to me, but maybe not to others. In which case `ref` might be better, right?

Comment: @iavr Definetely, I had no idea what `R` was for actually. It's good that your public interface is clean, but it's even better if other people can understand and maintain your code :)